# Error in python: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing transfer learning(vgg16) in python. My images are 512*512. As Vgg16 takes an input image of size 224*224, I am trying to divide each of my training images into several small patches. I would run my model into these small patches and would combine the individual results to get a final result for each of my training images. Please find my code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
patch_size=224
def prediction(model1, image, patch_size):
    segm_img = (np.zeros(image.shape[:2]))  
    patch_num=1
    for i in range(0, image.shape[0], 224):   #Steps of 224
        for j in range(0, image.shape[1], 224):  #Steps of 224
            #print(i, j)
             single_patch = image[i:i+patch_size, j:j+patch_size]
             single_patch_norm = np.expand_dims(normalize(np.array(single_patch),axis=1),2)
             single_patch_shape = single_patch_norm.shape[:2]
             single_patch_input = np.expand_dims(single_patch_norm, 0)
             single_patch_prediction = (model.predict(single_patch_input)[0,:,:,0] > 
             0.5).astype(np.uint8)
             segm_img[i:i+single_patch_shape[0], j:j+single_patch_shape[1]] += 
                      cv2.resize(single_patch_prediction, single_patch_shape[::-1])
             print("Finished processing patch number ", patch_num, " at position ", i,j)
             patch_num+=1
return segm_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   validation_split=0.10,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
 test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
 import glob
 import cv2  
 training_set = [cv2.imread(file) for file in 
                 glob.glob("D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllNewOriginalImage/Training/*.png")]
 new_training_set = prediction(model, training_set, patch_size)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-7f5dc4c94b8c> in <module>
----> 1 new_training_set = prediction(model, training_set, patch_size)

<ipython-input-110-71e724069bfc> in prediction(model1, image, patch_size)
      1 def prediction(model1, image, patch_size):
----> 2     segm_img = (np.zeros(image.shape[:2]))  #Array with zeros to be filled with segmented values
      3     segm_img=np.array(segm_img)
      4     patch_num=1
      5     for i in range(0, image.shape[0], 224):   #Steps of 224
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: you've provided way too much code that is not connected to your question. The error suggests, that you are not using a numpy array, but just a regular list.

Comment: What are you passing into the ```prediction``` function for the ```image``` argument?

Comment: you are passing list of images as image to the prediction method, native python lists doesn't have the shape property

Comment: Hi @Mark,
I was trying to combine the results of the individual patches of images that would give me the result of the original single image. I would like to run the model into all the images in the folder.

Comment: Hi @Black0ut,
My original image size is 512*512. As Vgg16 runs through images on 224*224, I was intending to run the model into small patches of images. The prediction function was intended to perform the patching operation.

Comment: @farabee, from the stack trace what I am seeing is that you are trying to call ```.shape()``` on a variable with type ```list```. But a ```list``` does not have ```shape``` as a method to call. If you have ```type(image)``` you'll see it returns a list. If I have to take a guess I think your image is supposed to be of type ```numpy```? Type numpy will allow you to call ```shape()```

Comment: You can convert your image from list to numpy by ```numpy.array(image)```, dont' forget to ```import numpy```. Not sure if that is exactly what you need though.

Comment: Hi @Mark,
Thank you for the suggestion. It worked.

Comment: Hi @Mark,
I had another query. I wanted to apply Vgg16 on my 512*512 image. As Vgg16 takes an input image of 224*224, can you suggest a way in which I can implement the process? The above method was one of the ways I tried to use for implementing the process. But I was unable to achieve the final goal.

Comment: @farabee, I think there are multiple ways to deal with this situation but I'm not sure which is the best. I think the simplest solution is just to set the vgg shape to match your image size. I think the following works ```vgg = VGG16(weights=None,classes=25,input_shape=(256,256,3))```.  Alternatively you could sample 244 by 244 image from your 256 by 256 image. This is obviously trickier as you may not necessarily sample what you want, although you can sample multiple times? My knowledge with image processing is limited, this is based on my experience with NN

Comment: Maybe this helps too, https://forums.fast.ai/t/vgg16-with-different-image-resolutions/4948

Comment: Hi @Mark,
Thank you for the suggestions.